# how to concatenate two string in `onkeyup` property in template in django

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I want to use a `request.session` variable in my template (for example like `.` operator in php )but this doesn't work:

```
<textarea onkeydown="if(event.keyCode ==13)Dajaxice.social.dajaxice_example(my_callback, {'text':$('#createPost').val() , 'user':". {{ request.session.first_name}} ."}) "></textarea><br />
                <input id="postButton"type="button" value="share" onclick="Dajaxice.social.dajaxice_example(my_callback, {'text':$('#createPost').val() , 'user':{{request.session.first_name}}})" />
            </
```

how can I concatenate these in django ?thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have the request context processor enabled.

Comment: yes I use it. I currently have a problem with concatenating two string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it a as a single string, you don't have to use  {{ request.session.first_name}} outside of quotes, django will handle it for you.

```
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode ==13)Dajaxice.social.dajaxice_example(my_callback, {'text':$('#createPost').val() , 'user': {{ request.session.first_name}} }) "
```

Comment: what's the output ? This should work, i just tested it.
try escaping the quotes around the django variable if you want first_name to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything to "concatenate" the template variable. Think of it like the whole html is a string and while rendering, `{{ request.session.first_name}}` will get replaced by the value of `request.session.first_name`.

```
<textarea onkeydown="if(event.keyCode ==13) Dajaxice.social.dajaxice_example(my_callback, {'text':$('#createPost').val() , 'user': '{{ request.session.first_name}}' }) "></textarea>
```